# Why Do I Get 'Illegal characters in path' in My Visual Basic Code?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a directory with multiple sub directories that contain .doc files. Example:

```
C:\Users\tmedina\Documents\testenviroment\Released\500\test0.doc
C:\Users\tmedina\Documents\testenviroment\Released\501\test1.doc
C:\Users\tmedina\Documents\testenviroment\Released\502\test2.doc
...
C:\Users\tmedina\Documents\testenviroment\Released\520\test20.doc
```

In my code below, I am trying to display in a list box all of the files that end with extension '.doc' that are in sub directories of `C:\Users\tmedina\Documents\testenviroment\Released`

So for example, I have

```
Dim root As String = "C:\Users\tmedina\Documents\testenviroment"

For Each fileFound As String In Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(root, "Released\*\*.doc"))
        ListBox1.Items.Add(fileFound)
    Next
```

But it keeps throwing out `Illegal characters in path` error.
Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filesystem doesn't understand the double `*` in `released\*\*.doc`
Directory.GetFiles oveload that takes only one argument doesn't like the partial path specification (....*.doc)

Try with this

```
Dim root As String = "C:\Users\tmedina\Documents\testenviroment\released" 

For Each fileFound As String In Directory.GetFiles(root, "*.doc", SearchOption.AllDirectories)) 
    ListBox1.Items.Add(fileFound) 
Next
```

The Visual Basic language doesn't need to escape the `\` character.
The Directory.GetFiles has an overload that takes your base path, a wildcard search string, and an option to search all of the subfolders of the base path.

Comment: Ah, nice call on the `SearchOption.AllDirectories`.  I don't use these methods much and I was in a hurry to post the answer as I was leaving work, so I didn't get a chance to check all the overloads.  Hope you don't mind if I steal that for my answer.  I hate leaving my answer in disrepair.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you are misusing the `GetFiles` method.  If you want to pass a search string such as "*.doc", you must do so as a second argument, such as:

```
Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(root, "Released"), "*.doc")
```

Also, you can't give it a folder path that contains a wildcard, such as "C:\Users\tmedina\Documents\testenviroment\Released*".  If you want all sub folders, you will need to specify the third parameter for search options:

```
Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(root, "Released"), "*.doc", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

Unless for some reason you don't want it to search all descendant directories and only want it to search the immediate child directories.  In that case, you would have to use `Directory.GetDirectories` to get a list of all the immediate sub-directories, then loop through them calling `GetFiles` for each one.